# Outputing text to command line when using C# and Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I am running Visual Studio 2010 and using C#.

I want to be able to launch an executable from the command line and be able to output text to the command window I launched from.

I tried these but they did not work at all.

Anybody have any ideas?

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("diag text");
Console.WriteLine("text");
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Console.WriteLine should do the trick.  Are you encountering an exception?

Comment: are you running a console application?  Do you see the console window  or a blank form when you run your application?

Comment: When I build in VS it builds a .exe file. and I  go to a command window and run the .exe from there. I am expecting to see some output from this window but nothing. If I go to VS i can see output in the output window, but I don't care about that.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you are running a Console Application.  Once you've confirmed that, at the end add this line:

```
Console.ReadLine();
```

without it your application will run, and close before you are able to see the console.  Adding that line will make the application wait till you press a key to close.

Comment: If i start the program it will output things in the output window but when i go to the console tab there is just the prompt. How do I tell if its a console application???

Comment: When you created a new project did you choose "Console Application"?

Comment: I am not the one that created it.

Comment: Right click on the project and check the properties. It should tell what type of application it is

Comment: It is not a consle application.